# Split a list into increasing sequences using itertools

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have a list with mixed sequences like

```
[1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,1,2]
```

I want to know how I can use itertools to split the list into increasing sequences cutting the list at decreasing points. For instance the above would output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

this has been obtained by noting that the sequence decreases at 2 so we cut the first bit there and another decrease is at one cutting again there.

Another example is with the sequence

```
[3,2,1]
```

the output should be

```
[[3], [2], [1]]
```

In the event that the given sequence is increasing we return the same sequence. For example

```
[1,2,3]
```

returns the same result. i.e

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

For a repeating list like

```
[ 1, 2,2,2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1,1,1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

the output should be

```
[[1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

What I did to achieve this is define the following function

```
def splitter (L):
    result = []
    tmp = 0
    initialPoint=0
    for i in range(len(L)):
       if (L[i] < tmp):
           tmpp = L[initialPoint:i]
           result.append(tmpp)
           initialPoint=i
       tmp = L[i]
    result.append(L[initialPoint:])
    return result
```

The function is working 100% but what I need is to do the same with itertools so that I can improve efficiency of my code. Is there a way to do this with itertools package to avoid the explicit looping?

Comment: It this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se].

Comment: Yes. The code is working. I was thinking maybe itertools package has something to help improve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `numpy`, you can use `numpy.split`, this requires the index as split positions; since you want to split where the value decreases, you can use `numpy.diff` to calculate the difference and check where the difference is smaller than zero and use `numpy.where` to retrieve corresponding indices, an example with the last case in the question:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [ 1, 2,2,2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1,1,1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
np.split(lst, np.where(np.diff(lst) < 0)[0] + 1)

# [array([1, 2, 2, 2]),
#  array([1, 2, 3, 3]),
#  array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
#  array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Psidom already has you covered with a good answer, but another NumPy solution would be to use [`scipy.signal.argrelmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html) to acquire the local maxima, then `np.split`.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmax
arr = np.random.randint(1000, size=10**6)
splits = np.split(arr, argrelmax(arr)[0]+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume your original input array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

First find the places where the splits shall occur:

```
p = [ i+1 for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:])) if x > y ]
```

Then create slices for each such split:

```
print [ a[m:n] for m, n in zip([ 0 ] + p, p + [ None ]) ]
```

This will print this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

I propose to use more speaking names than `p`, `n`, `m`, etc. ;-)